# Touchstart event is not firing inside iframe iOS 6

Tags: javascript, dom, ios6

I have a problem while selecting the text in IOS 6.The *touchstart* event is not firing inside an iframe while in iOS 6.  On iOS 5 this is working fine.

Comment: are we talking iframes in same origin / domain? or third party such as YouTube ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also had the same problem but only in some of my iframes. Why only some of them, I don't know.

But I managed to get the event firing consistently in all of them by explicitly having an event listener on touchstart events in the context of the document containing the iframes.

So adding the following code for the doc containing the iframe was the workaround for me.

```
function dummy() {
    // console.log("A bug? Where?");
}

addEventListener("touchstart", dummy, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this problem - the touchstart event is firing just fine for me inside an iframe.  I would expect that instead you are getting an exception before accomplishing whatever it is that your touchstart event tried to do.  Try putting an alert in the iframe, or, putting a try catch block around the body of the touchstart handler, and then alerting what the exception is.