# Extjs web app link in iFrame in iPad is not responding

Tags: ios, ipad, iframe, extjs

We are loading Extjs Web app from our existing web app. We done something like this below

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/"></iframe>
```

When we open this localhost link iPad safari. iFrame is loaded fine, but when I click on buttons or links it is not responding.

If I replace iframe src link to something else, it works fine. Is it know Extjs issue or is there any workaround for this.

Thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. Eventually, it turns out that this is an iOS iframe problem that doesn't pass "touchstart" event to iframe.

To solve problem put this code to the parent window :

```
function dummy() {
   // console.log("A bug? Where?");
}
addEventListener("touchstart", dummy, false);
```

You can see original post from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363742/touchstart-event-is-not-firing-inside-iframe-ios-6)